# django import_export Users password not encoded

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-import-export

I use library `from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin`
to make admin enterface get file xls ..csv ..etc

so I can enter a lot of data just by enter one file with all data.

The problem is when I export fill Users  then fail all data I find the password not encoded.

admin.py:

```
    from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from student.models import Students, CustomUser

   




class UserModel(UserAdmin):
    pass
class UserModel2(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(CustomUser , UserModel2)
```

I don't know how to use  `from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password`
to solve this problem.

Comment: You could create a new [Widget](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html) to handle encoding of the password at the point of saving to the db

Comment: where i create it ?